# Laravel Custom Middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

I am trying to achieve this using middleware

**web.php**

`Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index')->middleware('TestLogin');`

redirect to /test if session is found

`Route::get('/test1', 'TestController@index1')->middleware('TestLogin');`

redirect to test1 if session is set

**Middleware -TestLogin**

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)`
    { 
        if($request->session()->get('Username'))
        {
            return redirect()->route(\);
            // what to write here to redirect to the path its being called from

        }
        
        return redirect()->route('login');
        
}
```

don't want to use default auth middleware

Comment: why would you redirect to the current url, which would create an infinite loop? ... if you want the request to make it to the controller you let it pass through the stack     `return $next($request);` ... that is how you let it pass through

Comment: probably i was not able to explain ,y question perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Your middleware is suppose to check the login (session), if it is not found then redirect to login page otherwise it should pass the request. Something like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{ 
    // No login session, redirect
    if(!$request->session()->get('Username'))
    {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    // Pass the request down the rest of pipeline
    return $next($request);       
        
}
```

You should consider to use built in [authentication system in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication) itself, it will save you lots of code and you can be sure the auth is handled correctly in security point of view.

Comment: thanks buddy i followed same but its redirecting to request but then instantly returning back to login

Comment: And did you mention that `!` sign in condition?